# Images not displaying In css/jquery slider

Tags: jquery, css, easyslider

I've got 12 divs set to display a thumbnail and some text dynamically from a database call. On their own they display down the page, no problem ... div+border, thumbnail, text.

I'm then trying to put those 'boxes' into a horizontal slider, so the visitor can scroll through them if interested.

My problem is, the thumbnails won't display ... the div/box shows up OK, as does the text, but the images don't show?

The img tag is definitely correct, so I'm thinking I need to add a display or z-index tag to one of the divs, but I'm going round in circles at the moment.

Any suggestions please?  ( I'm using easyslider 1.7 )

HTML:

```
<div id="samplesales">
<div id="samplecontent">
<div id="slider">
<ul>
<li><div class=sample>
      <img src='..path/to/photo'>
      Photo description text ...
    </div>
</li>
  ....
<li><div class=sample> another photo etc </div></li>
</ul>
</div></div></div>
```

CSS

```
#samplesales{margin:0 auto;position:relative;text-align:left;width:650px;}
#samplecontent{position:relative;}

#slider ul, #slider li,
#slider2 ul, #slider2 li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    }

#slider2{margin-top:1em;}

#slider li, #slider2 li{ 
width:650px;
height:220px;
overflow:hidden; 
    margin:auto;
    display: block;
}

div.sample {
    display:block;
    border: solid 1px #0066CC;
    margin:6px; 
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: courier;
    min-height: 170px;
    vertical-text-align:middle;
    float:left;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #ccc;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing overflow:hidden to overflow:visible !important can't suggest mucj at this point it would probably overflow

Comment: Thanks Kinghtowl ... tried that but no good. Seems to lose the images when I put them in the 'samplesales' div. Think I'd better just make some graphics instead. Cheers